# Best Practices i18n XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I got an XML like that

```
<xml>
    <Entry id="MyEntry">
        <TimeRange>
            <Start>9:00</Start>    
            <End>23:00</End>
        </TimeRange>
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter>
                <Name>MyParam</Name>
                <Value>asadad</Value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <Name>MyParam2</Name>
                <Value>sdsd</Value>
            </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
    </Entry>
    <Entry id="MyEntry2">
        <TimeRange>
            <Start>9:00</Start>    
            <End>23:00</End>
        </TimeRange>
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter>
                <Name>MyParam</Name>
                <Value>askkad</Value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <Name>MyParam2</Name>
                <Value>sdksd</Value>
            </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
    </Entry>
</xml>
```

What would be the best approach for localize it per country (fr,de...)?

- Add to every final element an enumeration   for each value
- Enclose the whole structure in a lang=code
- Describe each entry per id and country like in Entry id="a" lang="fr", Entry id="a" lang="de"
- ...

There are indded a lot of ways but I'd like to know what is regarded as the standard, to avoid any forthcoming issues.

Comment: I answered your question as I understood the scenario but I recommend that you clarify your use case: how exactly should the data be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your scenario, you have a set of entries that you'd like to store in an XML with localisations for some or all of the child elements for various country codes. Understandably

In this case, the best practice depends on how you'll be using the data. If the entries will be used as input for a localised application, it makes sense to localise at the highest level: either create multiple documents/files for every country code or create a single document with multiple countries as the top level tag.

```
<xml country='DE'>
    <Entry>...
    <Entry>...
</xml>

<xml>
    <country id='DE'>
        <Entry>...
    </country>
</xml>
```

If however you want the localised data for multiple countries after you read an entry the localised values could be stored at the lowest level in a variety of ways:

```
<Entry id="MyEntry1">
    <TimeRange>
        <Start>9:00</Start>    
        <End>23:00</End>
    </TimeRange>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
            <Name>MyParam</Name>
            <Value country='DE'>askkad</Values>
            <Value country='FR'>sdksd</Values>
        </Parameter>
    </Parameters>
</Entry>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow [W3C's Best Practices for XML Internationalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-i18n-bp/)  In particular, section 4 provides guidance on using xml:lang in your XSD; other sections show examples of using lang, xml:lang, etc.  When specifying languages, use the specified [language tags from IETF](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/).

When designing your schema, you'll need to consider:

1. Will multiple languages be allowed?  I prefer this approach for
   supporting multi-lingual apps, e.g., displaying en-US & fr-CA
   simultaneously
2. Will the XML document be stored in toto, or will
   elements be spliced in? Splicing is more work, but allows for
   smaller payloads; well designed schema ensures integrity of spliced
   doc